# do some browsers auto resize content?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have completed my first site, bar resizing it for different screen sizes.
I have read up on how to do this, but before I start I wanted to find out if certain browsers (for example chrome for windows 8) automatically resize content to fit the screen?

I built my site on a 20inch screen, yet when I view it on my 11.6inch laptop (in chrome), the page fits perfectly on the page. However, load it on an old square 17inch monitor and everthing it HUGE and you have to scroll non stop just to get anywhere. The same happens loading it on my laptop in other browsers.

So if I create a CSS file with smaller properties and run a media query, am I risking shrinking the page that fits perfectly already in chrome?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you are using an old 17" screen with a low resolution.

As there are less pixels per inch everything appears larger.

Check the display resolution of each screen and you should see what I mean.

Comment: that makes sense. so essentially is it the resolution that will determine how objects are resized, as opposed to the actual size of the screen?

Comment: When designing responsive sites screen resolution is certainly something you need to be aware of. I'd do a bit of research in to both desktop and mobile screen dimensions.

Comment: Also if you are interested in designing responsive sites look up mobile first design.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the developer life.

If you want to a clear answer for your question, you have to write your sample code.

Possibilities are:

Give a fixed width or percentage to your wrapper div. If you want to use responsiveness, then you can you use media queries.

Or you can just start with a framework like bootstrap 3.

http://getbootstrap.com/

Comment: Bootstrap isn't a magic wand that solves all responsiveness problems.

Comment: It can be for a starter.